# Passing class name into function parameter

Tags: javascript, html

Im working with this part of code:

```
<div class="tabs-buttons-container">
            <button class="tabs-button" onclick="openTabs(event, 'test11', 'red')">Tab 1</button>
            <button class="tabs-button" onclick="openTabs(event, 'test12')">Tab 2</button>
            <button class="tabs-button" onclick="openTabs(event, 'test13')">Tab 3</button>
            <span class="test"></span>
            <span class="red"></span>
            <span class="white"></span>
        </div>
```

```
const openTabs = (event, tab, test) => {
    let i, tabContent, tabButton;

    tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs-content")

    for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
        tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementsByClassName(test).style.display = "block";
}
```

My current goal is to pass class "red" into function and change the display of span element. When im using ID it works fine but when i want to pass class the result is null. Is this possible to dynamically pass class name inside JS function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` return a collection, so you need to go through each element to assign the style. You can also use `querySelector("." + className)` which return only the first matched element.

Comment: Oh i've totaly forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var red = document.getElementByClassName('red')[0];
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25716951)